# JRating plugin change the star image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery [JRating](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/) plugin for rating.I want to change the star image  with another image. but when i replace it is not showing corretly. any one have idea to change ?

I want to replace the star with this below image. I have changed the image in the plugin like this

```js
var defaults = {
  /** String vars **/
  bigStarsPath: '/images/white.png', // path of the icon stars.png
  smallStarsPath: '/images/small.png', // path of the icon small.png
  phpPath: 'jrating/php/jRating.php', // path of the php file jRating.php
  type: 'big', // can be set to 'small' or 'big'
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".basic").jRating();
});
```

It never show correctly